# Error after changing column name

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-model-first

I'm using Entity Framework model-first. Recently I've changed in my table `Clip` a column name from `PropertyName` to `Name`. `Clip` has a foreign key with the id of table `Main`. I want to add a new record to table `Main`, but I'm receiving a weird exception:

> Invalid column name 'PropertyName'.

I refreshed the edmx, changed DTOs and it didn't help. I don't know what to do. 
What is wrong here? Why does my program still remember this column name, and why does it happen when I add a record to table `Main`?

Comment: Did you update the database?

Comment: Yes. I had changed database first, and then i changed my code

Comment: Did the refresh not just _add_ the `Name` column, in stead of _replacing_ the `PropertyName` column?